# Get the index of an element in a List that satisfies a condition

Tags: c#, linq

Say I have a `Point`:

```
public class Point
{
    double X, Y;
}
```

I want to get the index of the element inside `List<Point>` that satisfy a condition, for example, with the maximum `Point.X` value inside `List<Point>`.

How would I do that with a LINQ expression?

Answer (score 6):

You can do using [this `Select()` overlaod](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534869%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which takes index of item as well:

```
 var result = Points.Select((Point,Index)=> new { Index,Point})
                    .OrderByDescending(x=>x.Point.X).First().Index;
```

Comment: cannot access the Index property. And why only `OrderByDescending` won't work here?

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh see https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZzuMyb